# DotNetNuke- is there a way to export all the files in a portal?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN. We want to export all the files in the portal. We tried export using super account. Is there any other approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to export all files from the portal within the actual DNN Interface.

Your best option is to simply copy the directory from the site, the normal location on disk for these files is the `/Portals/{PortalID}/` folder.  Where PortalID is the # of the portal.

Comment: Thanks. I can find the files in the directory. Is there a way to view files inside database folder type?

Comment: No, in this case the files are stored as blobs in the database. The only way to get these files is to create a standard folder and copy or move the files from the database folder to the standard folder.